How to copy data to new sheet if condition is met?

I am trying to copy data to a new sheet in Excel using VBA.
I want the data to transfer to a sheet when marked "Complete".

My problem with the code down below is that the data always moves to row B in sheet 2, repeatedly overwriting itself.

I want the data copied to new rows in columns B, C, D, E, etc. in the
2nd sheet.

Code:
Sub Move_When_Completed()
'Created by Excel 10 Tutorial
    
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long

    A = Worksheets("To_Do").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    B = Worksheets("Done").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If B = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Done").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
    End If

    Set xRg = Worksheets("To_Do").Range("E1:E" & A)

    On Error Resume Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For C = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Complete" Then
            xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Done").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            xRg(C).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Complete" Then
                C = C - 1
            End If
            B = B + 1
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


You're doing the End(xlUp) on Column A - looks like you have no data in column A so it is always finding the first cell to be the "last" cell. Change it to be ...Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)...

Have you considered using the FILTER function? Something like =FILTER('Sheet1'!A1:E100,'Sheet1'!E1:E100="Complete")

Instead of Copy/Paste, just set the value of the cell you want the data in to value of the cells the data came from.

Move Matching Rows
Before

After

Edit

When copying entire rows, you have no choice but to copy to column A.
If you want to copy to column B, you need to apply only two changes:

Replace "A" with "B".

Replace With surg.EntireRow with
With Intersect(surg.EntireRow, sws.UsedRange)





The Code
Sub MoveCompleted()
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it isn't, reference it by name or use 'ActiveWorkbook'.
    
    ' Reference the source objects.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("To_Do")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.UsedRange.EntireRow.Columns("E")
    
    ' Reference the destination objects.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Done")
    Dim dcell As Range:
    With dws.UsedRange.EntireRow.Columns("A")
        Set dcell = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim surg As Range, sRow As Long, scell As Range
    
    ' Loop through the cells of the source range
    ' and add the matching (completed) cells to a unioned range.
    For Each scell In srg.Cells
        If CStr(scell.Value) = "Complete" Then ' E<>e
        'If StrComp(CStr(scell.Value), "Complete", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' E=e
            If surg Is Nothing Then
                Set surg = scell
            Else
                Set surg = Union(surg, scell)
            End If
        End If
    Next scell

    ' Check if any matching cells were found and retrieve their number.
    Dim MatchingRowsCount As Long
    If Not surg Is Nothing Then MatchingRowsCount = surg.Cells.Count
    
    ' Copy and delete the entire rows of the unioned range.
    If MatchingRowsCount > 0 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            With surg.EntireRow
                .Copy Destination:=dcell
                .Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
    
    ' Inform.
    If MatchingRowsCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox MatchingRowsCount & " completed row" _
            & IIf(MatchingRowsCount = 1, "", "s") & " moved.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No completed rows found!", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub

